# Treacherous Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

If I have an Euler-Lagrange equation:
$(y')^2 = 2 (1-\cos(y))$ where $y$ is a function of $x$ subjected to boundary conditions $y(x) \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$ and $y(x) \to 2\pi$ as $x \to +\infty$, how might I find all its solutions?

I can't seem to directly integrate the equation and sub in the conditions... Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complementary to solutions of [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) and [Sivaram](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3302/sivaram) you could differentiate your equation once to get

$$2 y''(x) y'(x) = 2 y'(x) \sin y(x)$$

which implies $y''(x) = \sin y(x)$. After substitution $y(x)=\pi - \theta(x)$ this translates into $\theta''(x) = -\sin \theta(x)$ which is the pendulum equation. Your boundary condition require that $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} \theta(x) = \pi$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} \theta(x) = -\pi$. Hence the solution is not periodic.

This trajectory is described by the [Gudermannian function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html).

Comment: @Sasha: Thanks! I have never met the pendulum equation before... So what are "all the solutions" to the problem?

Comment: Generally @scoobs, you'll need elliptic integrals and elliptic functions to solve the problem. The Gudermannian pops up since it's a special case of the [Jacobi amplitude function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html): $\mathrm{am}(u\mid 1)=\mathrm{gd}(u)$.

Comment: In any event, [this](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/ACQ7072.0001.001?view=toc) is a bit dated as a reference, but you would want to see the first chapter where the pendulum equation is dealt with.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks! Hmm... elliptic integrals/functions? They are alien to me too... Would these particular boundary conditions somehow simplify the general proceedure to allow a special simple(r) case?

Comment: @scoobs: The Gudermannian is pretty elementary :) The thing is that the elliptic integrals and elliptic functions become elementary when a certain quantity called the *parameter* takes on either of the values 0 or 1. In any event, you really might want to try looking at the book, it should be readable even if you haven't dealt with these beasties previously.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks! I shall do exactly that :)

Answer (score 2):

Use $1-\cos y=1-(\cos^2\frac y2-\sin^2\frac y2)=2\sin^2\frac y2$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $2\sin^2\frac{y}{2}$?

Comment: @J.M.: Indeed. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

$1-\cos(y) = 2 \sin^2 \left( \frac{y}{2} \right)$. Hence, $y'^2 = 4 \sin^2 \left( \frac{y}{2} \right) \implies y' = \pm 2 \sin \left( \frac{y}{2} \right)$